CNOT gate on an entangled target qubit
When the target qubit of the CNOT gate is in an entangled state, it is understood that the CNOT gate affects that one only and not the qubit entangled with target one. This follows from a recent reply in a similar question was very kindly answered in CNOT gate when the target qubit is in entangled state.
I would like to ask whether this understanding is correct and there is no misunderstanding from my side. Thank you.

The result of applying the $CNOT$ gate to an entangled state are below. Note only the target qubit is affected as you thought.
$CNOT_{02}|1\rangle \otimes (\frac{|{00}\rangle + |{11}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}) \mapsto (\frac{|{01}\rangle + |{10}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}})$
$CNOT_{01}|1\rangle \otimes (\frac{|{00}\rangle + |{11}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}) \mapsto (\frac{|{10}\rangle + |{01}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}})$
$CNOT_{02}|1\rangle \otimes (\frac{|{00}\rangle - |{11}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}) \mapsto (\frac{|{01}\rangle - |{10}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}})$
$CNOT_{01}|1\rangle \otimes (\frac{|{00}\rangle - |{11}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}) \mapsto (\frac{|{10}\rangle - |{01}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}})$
